# Is there a word that means "derivative-able"?

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

I'm just curious, so is there a word that you could use to express that a mathematical function has a derivative?

Comment: The word is *"differentiable"*.

Comment: Right. And the process of calculating the derivative of a function is called _differentiation_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> [Introduction to Differential Calculus: Systematic Studies ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=vk2XbZpsBOwC&pg=PT239&dq=%22function%20has%20a%20derivative%22%20is%20termed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nuweVbHqPKeasQTAnoCAAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22function%20has%20a%20derivative%22%20is%20termed%22&f=false) Ulrich
>   L. Rohde, ‎G. C. Jain, ‎Ajay K. Poddar - 2012
>
> If a **function has a derivative** at x1 of its domain, then it is said to
>   be **differentiable** at x1 ...
>   Differentiable Function: If a function is differentiable at every
>   number in its domain, it is called a **differentiable function.**